# How to write this xml code in form of Annotation in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

i have this piece of code written in xml.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <!-- Use the HibernateAware mapper instead of the default -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.ekiras.util.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

How can i write the same functionlity using annotations in Spring or Spring Boot.

Comment: i have no clue how to start converting this xml based configuration to annotation based configuration.. any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new HibernateAwareObjectMapper());
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```